# bindData include with nested params

Tags: grails, data-binding

Given the following classes:

**Simplified example:**

```
class Query {
    Institution institution
}

class Institution {
    String name
}
```

With the following parameters being submitted: `query.institution.id=20` and `query.institution.name=Example`

I would like to include only the institution id and ignore the name from being bound to the query's institution instance.

Is it possible with bindData to explicitly include associated instance's that are nested multiple levels like this?

I haven't seen any examples of this, aside from using the prefix for a single level of nesting, and the following does not seem to work:

**Simplified example:**

```
bindData(queryInstance, params, [include: [
    'institution.id',
]], 'query')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to filter your request parameters through a command object, which can then be used to generate any kind of query.

```
Command cmd = Command.getInstance()
bindData(cmd, request.params)
if (cmd.validate()) Query query = cmd.generateQuery()
```

This way you get the benefit of binding only to fields you expose on the command object, while validating and transforming incoming data without involving your domain.